# Firebase free account plan vs GCM

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

What is difference for each:

1)
`Realtime Database` - 1 GB
`Simultaneous connections` - 100 connections
`Storage` - 5 GB
`Hosting` - 1 GB

2)
Also difference between `Firebase Cloud Messaging` which is said to be free and `Firebase` have pricing.

3)
How it is different than GCM services.

Can anyone elaborate?

Thanks

Comment: Unlimited free Notifications are provided as part of the spark plan on firebase fyi.

Comment: Is web based notifications/desktop notifications allowed in fcm?

Comment: see here: https://firebase.google.com/features/

Answer (score 0):

The GCM website: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging states:

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits
>   the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! See
>   the FAQ to learn more. If you are integrating messaging in a new app,
>   start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM,
>   in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.